# Overriding Woocommerce checkout fields with ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, filter-woocommerce

I have a woocommerce site where i override some of the checkout fields based on the selected country. For this I am using

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields', 10000 );
```

This works great when the checkout page is loaded or reloaded.

But when a customer changes the country in the form dropdown on checkout the fields are updated via ajax:

```
?wc-ajax=update_order_review
```

And when this happens my filter for `woocommerce_checkout_fields` is never run.

How do i get my override to work with the ajax update aswell?

Comment: How did you manage this problem? I'd also like to update the fields using ajax